# Error Code -36 Copying Files from Windows NT Formatted Drive to exFAT Drive (select files only)

Tags: finder, external-disk, error, file-transfer, disk-format

The gist of the problem is this: I have a large amount of video and audio footage that I need to consolidate from multiple drives - namely this Windows NT Filesystem formatted Seagate Expansion Drive to a newly formatted exFAT WD My Passport drive.

Right now I've encountered a Error Code -36: The Finder can't complete the operation because some data in "File Name.mov" can't be read or written. (Error code -36).

HOWEVER, I've successfully moved 95%+ of the files from the Seagate External Hard Drive to the exFAT WD My Passport hard drive. Only a handful of files produce this error. Problem files are various sizes, from 1.39 to 3.98 GB. Both larger and smaller files have moved successfully.

I've spent hours scouring the internet and trying different solutions, with no success. I've researched this problem with no luck.

Things I've tried so far:

- rebooting iMac / External Drives
- copying a problem file to a different exFAT drive
- copying a problem file to my iMac desktop
- copying a problem file to a different folder on the problem external drive
- compressing a problem file
- checked the permissions on the files that are problem: they say I can read and write but do not show a profile with permissions as normal files do
- ran First Aid on Disk Utility on the Windows-formatted drive, it said there was some possible problem with the tree, but I don't think this is the issue as I can access the drive's contents and copy most of the files
- came across the dot file solution but these aren't dot files. Unsure if attempted implementation properly but no change.

My Set-Up:

iMac Sierra 10.12.6
Seagate Expansion Drive, Windows NT Format
WD MyPassport Drive, exFAT Format

This problem is particularly frustrating because when copying a folder, if a problem file is in it it stops the transfer... meaning I have to manually copy batches of the files at a time, and spend a lot of extra time identifying the problem files.

What do I do? Please help!